# If an object's weight could be reduced to zero, how high would it rise in the atmosphere?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity

### Rocks that float and the madness that ensues

Hello, this is a question in two parts:

1- If an object could have its weight reduced to zero, how high would it float up? Let's say a 20kg rock having an anti-gravity handwavium of 20kg upwards. The maximum height would be determined by its volume?

2- If I jumped from a cliff while hugging that rock. Considering my weight being 80kg. How would that change my fall? I´m guessing not much as the rock wouldn't be displacing much air. But I will trust the experts to help me figure this one out.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "stone" is pushed upwards by (following Archimedes' principle) a force $F=\rho V_{stone}g$, where $\rho$ denotes the density of the air surrounding the stone (depends on the height of the stone) and $g$ is the gravitational constant (with increasing height of the stone this would reduce too), but after all there always is a non-zero force, meaning the stone would go infinitely far up.

In the second part, the stone acts like a hot air balloon or a helium-filled balloon: Depending on its volume, it exerts a force which slows down your fall or even pulls you up.

Comment: Thank you. I read that around 10km up the air pressure is roughly half of that at ground level. Would that mean that if I attached a 10kg on the stone it would stop at that height?

Comment: No, definitely not! This highly depends on the stone's volume!

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Let's say that I had a slab of 18m3, and weight zero that would give me around 18kg of buoyancy at ground level. Would in this case a ballast of 9kg make it stop rising at 10km?

Comment: I have no idea where you are pulling these numbers from. Firstly: The density of air at a pressure of $101.325kPa$ and at $15°C$ is $1.225kg/m^3$, hence a "rock" of $18m^3$ would (at sea level) have a force of $F=mg=V\rho g\approx 216N$ pulling the attached weight upwards. Therefore the weight is accelerated upwards with roughly its gravitational acceleration, i.e. it is "free falling" upwards. Therefore at a height of 10km it would have reached a speed of about $400$ to $500m/s$ or in other words around $1600km/h$ which would lead to some sort of oscillation.

Comment: To determine the height at which such a construction consisting of a weight and a "weightless rock" would be in equilibrium i.e. neither falling nor moving upwards if released at zero velocity, you would need the following: Use the barometric height formula, to get the atmospheric pressure, relate this to the density of air at that height (gives buoyancy force); use Newton's gravitational law to calculate $g=G\frac{m_{earth}}{(r_{earth}+h)^2}$ where $h$ is the height above sea level at which you are. Then you can set $F_{buoyancy}=F_g$ and solve for the height at which this holds.

Comment: Maybe what I'm about to say will terrify you, but I was using the numbers based on this line of thought. Buoyant force on an object is equal to the weight of the fluid displaced by the object, so I rounded the density of air at ground level from 1.225kg/m³ to 1.0kg/m³. The rock having 18m³ would displace air and that would result in a upward force of 18kg. Is that really bad? I´m trying my best. So, giving it a ballast of 9kg would leave only 9kg of upwards force. If at 10k the density of air is say around 50%, then the forces of buoyancy (now 9kg) would be equal to the ballast. Forgive me?

Comment: If you put it like this, the numbers roughly add up, yes. There is obviously a lot of approximations in there but I think in general you are correct.

Comment: Thanks! I´m sorry for asking in such layman's terms and for basically destroying math with those approximations. I wanted to grab the concept correctly before making any calculations. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Up Up an away into space.
2. 0+80Kg=80 Kg

Comment: So basically any amount of positive buoyant force will push an object into space? Is there anyway an object could achieve balance and remain at a certain height?

Comment: If there is no opposite gravitational force, yes, this is obviously the case.

Comment: @mcbecker There is no buoyancy effect here. Buoyancy does not exist without gravity. The object will go into space because it is weightless and not due to any buoyancy "push effect".

Comment: Oh ok. So sorry for not being clear. Let's say that I had a slab of 18m3, and weight zero that would give me around 18kg of buoyancy at ground level. Would in this case a ballast of 9kg make it stop rising at 10km?

Comment: Sorry, but you seem confused of what the buoyancy effect is? If there is no gravity there is no reaction from the medium density difference thus there is no buoyancy effect. Third Newton's Law.